# Android Studio How to animate a moving view?

Tags: android, android-studio, animation, textview, move

I have a Question. How can i animate a moving view ? I want to spawn an letter and animate it (rotate and scale) while moving. If I only start the animation it works as I want, or if I only run the move method it works too, but not together. Here are the screens of the code: 
The Move method gets called for every view by a run method of the mainactivity

```
    public Letter (FrameLayout container, Random rnd, Animation animation){

        view = new TextView(container.getContext());
        letter = letters[rnd.nextInt(letters.length)];
        view.setText(letter);
        view.setTextColor(Color.rgb(rnd.nextInt(256),rnd.nextInt(256),rnd.nextInt(256)));
        view.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        container.addView(view);
        x = container.getWidth();
        y = container.getHeight();
        vx = 2 * rnd.nextFloat() * (rnd.nextBoolean()?1:-1);
        vy = 2 * rnd.nextFloat() * (rnd.nextBoolean()?1:-1);
        view.startAnimation(animation);
        move();
    }

    public void move() {
        x+= vx;
        y+=vy;
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        params.leftMargin = Math.round(x);
        params.topMargin = Math.round(y);
        params.gravity = Gravity.LEFT+Gravity.TOP;
        view.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
```

---

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <!--<scale
        android:fromXScale="1"
        android:fromYScale="1"
        android:toXScale="3"
        android:toYScale="3"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:duration="10000"
        >
    </scale>
       -->

    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="360"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration = "3000"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        >
    </rotate>

</set>
```

Comment: please, include code as text, not as picture)

Comment: done...........

Answer (score 0):

When you move the view with your Move method, it conflicts with the animation trying to set the layout of the view.

You should either stick to animation objects and combine the moving in the xml along with the rotation and scaling, which I think is your best bet, or implement the rotation and scaling yourself (the same way you did for moving).

You can also try to use to override applyTransformation for the animation, and get the view position there and change it.